# Is there a single free/open-source command line tool to extract all archive/compression formats?

Tags: software-rec, compression, utilities

With an [increasing number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_archive_formats) of archive/compression file formats, is there a single free/open-source command line tool to rule them all? Perhaps something with a consistent / unified set of flags? (note my  friendly [implicit reference to tar](http://xkcd.com/1168/))

I once run into a set of aliases meant to largely simplify the task of compressing/de-compressing files with bindings to `tar` and other utils, but I can't find this anymore.

**Update:**
How can I configure something like `atool` to not use `unzip` to extract zip files (which apparently can't handle files larger than 4GB) and to use `gunzip` instead?

```
$ aunpack large_file.zip
error:  Zip file too big (greater than 4294959102 bytes)
Archive:  large_file.zip
warning [large_file.zip]:  1491344848 extra bytes at beginning or within zipfile
  (attempting to process anyway)
error [large_file.zip]:  start of central directory not found;
  zipfile corrupt.
  (please check that you have transferred or created the zipfile in the
  appropriate BINARY mode and that you have compiled UnZip properly)
aunpack: unzip ...: non-zero return-code
```

Comment: yet another solution: http://packages.qa.debian.org/u/unp.html

Comment: @frostschutz. Do you know if there is anything that may make `unpack` different from `atool`?

Comment: Dunno. As Evan's answer shows, such a program is fairly trivial. Use whatever works for you. For unpacking zip files, my personal preference is `7z`.

Comment: @user815423426 I've added instructions for your updated question to my existing answer.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/338758/how-to-quickly-extract-all-kinds-of-archived-files-from-command-line

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I use [atool](http://www.nongnu.org/atool/). It does the job. It works with many, though not all formats:

tar, gzip, bzip2, bzip, lzip, lzop, lzma, zip, rar, lha, arj, arc, p7zip etc.

These compression tools are still needed, though as atool is simply a front end for them.

I particularly like the `als` command it provides which lists the contents of any supported archive format.

The main `atool` command uses its own flags for extracting archives (passing the appropriate flags to the specific underlying extraction tools).

Oh, and it's in some distributions' repositories (Fedora in my case, though as I recall, back when I used Ubuntu it wasn't in their repos then. and I installed from a tarball.).

**Update on Repositories**: atool is in the following distributions' repositories (current releases checked only):

- Fedora
- Debian (thanks @terdon, and, presumably, it's derivatives
  like Ubuntu)
- Ubuntu (q.e.d., and, presumably, derivatives like
  Mint)
- Open Suse
- CentOS (and, presumably, RHEL)
- Arch Linux

I'm sure there are others... plausibly, most modern distributions.

**Answer for Updated Question "How can I configure something like atool to not use unzip to extract zip files ... and to use gunzip instead"**:

Edit the atool config file `~/.atoolrc` and add the line:

```
path_unzip /usr/bin/gunzip
```

with the correct path to your gunzip program.

See the man page for the complete list of possible variables you can put in this config file, of which there are **a lot**. If the command line options necessary for gunzip are different than unzip, you may have to modify the atool source (perl) itself.

Comment: Thanks. This looks great. Do you know if, aside from being able to download the tarball, there is a (git/bzr) repository for it, or perhaps for a fork of it?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a git repo for it. There is a, shudder, cvs repo: https://savannah.nongnu.org/cvs/?group=atool . However, the source is in the tarball and the tool is written in perl, so easily modifiable by you or anyone who feels the urge.

Comment: @user815423426 it is also in the Debian repos.

Answer (score 11):

Here's a little shell function that takes care of several archive types.

```
extract () {
    if [ ! -f "$1" ] ; then
        echo "'$1' does not exist."
        return 1
    fi

    case "$1" in
        *.tar.bz2)   tar xvjf "$1"   ;;
        *.tar.xz)    tar xvJf "$1"   ;;
        *.tar.gz)    tar xvzf "$1"   ;;
        *.bz2)       bunzip2 "$1"    ;;
        *.rar)       rar x "$1"      ;;
        *.gz)        gunzip "$1"     ;;
        *.tar)       tar xvf "$1"    ;;
        *.tbz2)      tar xvjf "$1"   ;;
        *.tgz)       tar xvzf "$1"   ;;
        *.zip)       unzip "$1"      ;;
        *.Z)         uncompress "$1" ;;
        *.xz)        xz -d "$1"      ;;
        *.7z)        7z x "$1"       ;;
        *.a)         ar x "$1"       ;;
        *)           echo "Unable to extract '$1'." ;;
    esac
}
```

I found the [original
version](http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bashrc_helpers) of this function
somewhere online and modified it a bit to extract `ar` archives and xz
compressed `tar` archives.

Comment: This looks great. Is this for bash?

Comment: I've only tested this with `bash` and `zsh`, but it should work with `sh` as well.

Comment: This is exceptionally aesthetically pleasing for a shell function. One caveat would be that you'd want to make sure you've got all the relevant binaries installed, or remove lines for those you don't have installed.

Answer (score 3):

The [AVFS](http://avf.sourceforge.net/) filesystem presents a view of the filesystem where every archive file (e.g. `/path/to/foo.zip`) is accessible as a directory (`~/.avfs/path/to/foo/zip#` for this example). AVFS provides read-only access to most common archive file formats.

```
mountavfs
cp -Rp ~/.avfs$PWD/large_file.zip\# extraction_directory
```

Avfs uses external helpers which can be easily configured by editing files in `/usr` (unfortunately there's no way as of avfs 1.0 to use files in `/usr/local` or in your home directory, you need to edit files in `/usr` or recompile). `/usr/share/avfs/extfs/ext-uzip` is the script to deal with `.zip` files, change it if you don't want to use `/usr/bin/unzip`. You may be able to get away with using 7z instead: try editing `/usr/share/avfs/extfs/extfs.ini` and change the line `ext-uzip` to `u7z .zip`.

Answer (score 1):

[libarchive](https://libarchive.org/) is a *Multi-format archive and compression library* that supports [many archive and compression formats](https://github.com/libarchive/libarchive/wiki/LibarchiveFormats).

`bsdtar` and `bsdcpio` are command-line interfaces to that with a `tar`-like a `cpio`-like API respectively.

So it you're already familiar with either of those utilities, that's one command-line interface less to learn.

To unpack your `.iso`, `.zip`, `.cab`, `.7z`, `.tar.gz.xz.bz2`... file, it's just:

```
bsdtar xf file.<ext>
```

Like you would do `tar xf file.tar` with a traditional `tar` command.