# Unzipping .tar.gz or .zip

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am writing a scriptwhere in a file there are .zip files and .tar.gz files. I have to extract the files. I know how to use tar for tar.gz and unzip for zip files but don't know how to take decision based on extensions. I have written a script which works for tar.gz. Here is the script.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Evaluate Lab"
select yn in "Yes" "No";
do
    case $yn in
    Yes )
        echo "Evaluating!!"
        #choose file
        file="$(ls | head -1)"
        echo $file

        mkdir temp
        echo "Decompressing file $file"
        #Decompress chosen tar.gz to temp
        tar -xf "$file" --directory temp

        cd temp/
        #Do some work here
        #get out of temp folder
        cd ../
        rm -rf temp
        echo "Moving $file to done"
        mv "$file" ../done/
        echo "Evaluate another"
        echo "1) Yes     2) No"
        ;;
    No )
        echo "Exiting...."
        exit;;
    *)
        echo "Enter right option";;
    esac
done
```

I've to work on both tar.gz and zip.  Any hints?

Comment: Your `ls | head -1` is poor practise. If you care to share a little more of your script we might be able to make suggestions on that too.

Comment: @roaima I've modified the description and added the partial script written by me.

Comment: How do you know that the `tar.gz` file that you are interested in is the first file returned by `ls`?

Comment: @Kusalananda  The file only contains compressed files. I'm assuming it is tar.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/73362/117549

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a variation on your script:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

mkdir -p "done"

for file in ./*.tar.gz ./*.zip; do
    printf 'Press Enter to process %s, or Ctrl+C to quit\n' "$file"
    read bogus

    tmpdir=$(mktemp -d)

    printf 'Decompressing %s into %s\n' "$file" "$tmpdir"
    case $file in
        *.tar.gz) tar -xz -f "$file" -C "$tmpdir" ;;
        *.zip)    unzip      "$file" -d "$tmpdir" ;;
    esac

    (
        cd "$tmpdir"
        # do work here

    )

    rm -rf "$tmpdir"
    mv "$file" "done"
done
```

It iterates over all `.tar.gz` and `.zip` files in the current directory.  For each file, a temporary extraction directory is created using `mktemp -d` and the file is extracted into it with `tar` or `unzip` depending on the filename suffix.

The subshell around the `cd` and whatever else you need to do to the extracted data allows you to skip changing directories back to where you started (the changed working directory is local to the subshell).

I suppose the main thing here is the `case ... esac` statement.  This is a way to do different things depending on what pattern a string matches.

See also:

- [About the `case` statement in the POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04_05).